# ElasticSearch CJK language analyser

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing data based on language ISO 639 code: en, de etc. using the out of the box analyzers.

When it comes to CJK (Chinese, Japanese, Korean), based on the language ISO code, should I indexing ja (Japanese) and ko (Korean) into the CJK index (assuming Chinese is separately supported as per the documentation)?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the indexing with separate analyzers for Chinese and Japanese. For Korean, they are yet to add analyzer.

For Chinese you need to install the smartcn-sentence plugin and add into your mappings. You can find the smartcn-analyzer here [smartscn-analyzer](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-smartcn)

For Japanese you need to install Kuromoji plugin. You can find the kuromoji analyzer here [Kuromoji-analyzer](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-kuromoji)